# Xfce on Xubuntu issues with WINE

Tags: wine, xfce, photoshop

I am having a heck of a time getting WINE to work correctly in Xfce on Xubuntu.  I need to use Photoshop CS, thus need to use WINE, but VM's are not an option as it's a pain to manage files back and forth, it's also slower.

But, the problem I am having is, in Gnome 2, MATE, and Unity, Photoshop CS works just great.  Nearly perfect actually.  But in Xfce, I can not get the interface to respond like it's supposed to.  I recorded a video showing how it's behaving.  Mind you, this happens with either a compositor (doesn't matter which one), or even WITHOUT a compositor.  I am very stern that I have tried with ZERO compositor because on Xfce's own forum, they keep bringing up a compositor as the problem, but I have definitely verified that no compositor is loaded, either it be Compiz, Compton, or Xfce's own (Xrender?).

Here's the video showing what problem I am getting here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJGxIDHgfrc

I really could appreciate some help.  In fact, if anyone also has Xubuntu 14.04, and has Photoshop CS, please try it on it and see if you get the same problem too.  I need to have this working as I am not about to fiddle with multiple desktop environments or VM's.  I shouldn't have to, it should all work in one DE.

Comment: Often it helps to enable Wine's virtual desktop. Open Wine settings, go to the video tab, enable the virtual desktop and set up the resolution. Now try again.

Comment: I tried that in the video. It semi works.  Only oddity is that the tools will not go on top of the main window.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is xfwm4, it makes the menu bar of some wine apps inaccessible.

Replace xfwm4 with, for example, openbox and the problem is gone.

Comment: Hello there, please include a more detailed answer.